How can is close an account that has .0102 XTZ in it so it will stop delegating?
I am trying to stop staking and close the account.  And can i sell it to Dust.   Any help is appreciated

The title of your question says "delegating", but the body of your question says "staking". These are different things.
Staking is when you lock a specific amount of your XTZ, and you must unstake them which takes ~11 days, before you can transfer. This offers a high rate of interest. If you are looking to unstake, you can use the staking application on tezos.com: https://stake.tezos.com/.
Delegating is when you just choose a baker and earn a small amount of interest on your entire balance, while it remains liquid at all times. If you are looking to stop delegating, you can send an undelegate command and then transfer the rest. However it actually costs more in transaction fees to do this. While delegating you are free to transfer everything except 0.000001 XTZ. The cheapest thing to do is to leave this small amount in your wallet and transfer everything else
